# Cloth simulation not appearing in render. Works and plays properly on viewport

Tags: rendering, physics

Been tackling this problem for some days now as I tried to get to the bottom of it. As the title says, I do a simple cloth sim, and even bake it. Upon rendering, the scene is as if no simulation was done at all. **This happens in both EEVEE and Cycles, cpu and gpu rendering. I tried it with disk cache enabled.** Tried it with all my addons removed and factory settings/preference. I've done this scene over 20 times the past few days in multiple blender versions (2.80, 2.83, 2,90). The only one where it does work normal as expected is v2.80.

Before anyone asks, yes, I checked the whether the cloth sim modifier is enabled.

At this point, Im thinking it may be a problem with my pc itself.

video demo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ecCX9WNuhONNx0Jenx6ZPD0TiGGLrxpW/view?usp=sharing
with disk cache enabled:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C6s2zcLgAY2SjazmpcsGAi3RJEtYPCxI/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT:**

**Okay, I've been testing a bit more and may have found some new leads**.

The startup file I use was changed a few times since 2.80. I've opened my 2.80 startup file in 2.83 and problem seem to not appear. (Simulation appearing in render as normal and expected.)

[2.83 startupfile](https://pasteall.org/blend/724d7a91bc93442399767d169b630b36)

[2.80 startup file](https://pasteall.org/blend/8c263d9238ab4964b775363dfe37c85b)

If someone could check if there is something I did with the 2.83 startup that could affect simulation rendering, that would be appreciated.

Comment: did you bake all the animations?

Comment: Yes. It's mentioned in the post. I've baked it.